# Weird canvas rendering bug in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, canvas

I'm using a canvas to render an image, and I'm experiencing this weird graphical bug appearing sometimes, which disappears as soon as I scroll.

This is part of a react component, [you can see the code for it here.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143805/react-image-component-that-loads-and-blurs-an-image-onto-a-canvas)

[image]

After scrolling or triggering an update of some kind in the rendering process, it looks as it should:

[image]

This is what the CSS for my image looks like:

```
.async-image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0)
}

.async-image canvas {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateZ(0)
}

.async-image .preload {
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.async-image .preload.ready {
  opacity: 1;
}

.async-image .src {
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.async-image .src.ready {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.async-image img {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Not sure what could be causing this, but there is an underlying canvas underneath as well on top of the main canvas, used to display a 10x10 blurred image of the source image, as a preloader. The image then zooms slightly in when it's ready.

This bug seems to trigger when I switch to another tab and then back also.

Comment: Looks like you are rendering over the top of the image, over and over. Maybe you forget to call `ctx.beginPath()` before rendering, or you dont clear the canvas before rendering again. But without the code we can only guess what is wrong..

Comment: That is not true, no. I am rendering it once. The image is actually a react component, only rendering on mount and when the source changes. And I am clearing the canvas before rendering it again, even then, how does that explain the issue disappearing on scroll?

Comment: Can you send a link to the website to check it out?

Comment: @divix Unfortunately, no. This is a project of mine and it's on my machine. I don't have a host.

Comment: You should post a demo that shows the actual problem. The CSS looks weird though. Did you try to remove all of the transform properties for a test?

Comment: @NicoO Posting a demo would be difficult considering this is part of a React.js component. I've added a link to a codereview question where you can see the code for it. I removed the transforms yeah. Same issue.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen If I were you, I'd write several isolated demos to determine which part caused the problem, either React, canvas, CSS or whatever, or a combination of them. Find out the smallest buggy case, then we can talk of the root cause and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

deleted my old answer...

Sorry, Didn't read that it was caused on switching tabs...

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(){
    // Add code to re render the canvas or repaint...
    // You can even try using window.scrollBy(0, 1); here ;P
})
```

This might be happening to prevent spending resources on unfocussed tabs by chrome...

If you wanna know inspect painting and FPS meter etc... Important for web animation... Enable it in chrome dev tools like this...

[image: Inspecting rendering in chrome]

Hope that helps...

Comment: This is more hacky than a fix. It is caused by switching tabs, but it doesn't happen all the time, sometimes it just happens while navigating my app. I seriously doubt it's got anything to do with my code, seeing as I have no code that listens for the scroll event that does anything with the image.

Comment: I thing it might being caused by OS or Chrome itself to save ram/cpu resources... It happens more aggressively on apple OSes... So I think you'll have to manually re render the page when it happens...

Comment: Scroll just triggers re-paint in chrome... ( re rendering visible elements )

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this issue and the one you linked to (about slow rendering), I'd try CSS filters as an alternative. Browser support is [pretty good](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter). If you need really wide browser support, [you can use SVG filters](http://thenewcode.com/534/Cross-browser-Image-Blur-with-CSS).